# documenting error Jazzy "0% documentation coverage with 0 undocumented symbols"

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, jazzy

So I'm trying to run Jazzy to document my code but I'm not getting very far.

This is what happens when i run Jazzy on my Xcode project written in swift(and some functions in @ objc). Do i need to prepare the project in any way? I can't find anything about this, but it's my first time using Xcode and jazzy.
Can anyone tell me why it's not able to run properly am i doing something wrong while running the command?

```
jazzy 
Running xcodebuild
Checking xcodebuild -showBuildSettings
Assuming New Build System is used.
Parsing AppDelegate.swift (1/4)
Parsing Card.swift (2/4)
Parsing SceneDelegate.swift (3/4)
Parsing ViewController.swift (4/4)
0% documentation coverage with 0 undocumented symbols
skipped 4 private, fileprivate, or internal symbols (use `--min-acl` to specify a different minimum ACL)
building site
building search index
jam out ♪♫ to your fresh new docs in `docs`
```

I tried doing jazzy --min-acl but this happens:

```
jazzy --min-acl
Traceback (most recent call last):
15: from /usr/local/bin/jazzy:23:in `<main>'
14: from /usr/local/bin/jazzy:23:in `load'
13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/bin/jazzy:15:in `<top (required)>'
12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/lib/jazzy/config.rb:442:in `parse!'
11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/lib/jazzy/config.rb:485:in   `parse_command_line'
10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1678:in `parse!'
 9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1656:in `permute!'
 8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1562:in `order!'
 7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1568:in `parse_in_order'
 6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1568:in `catch'
 5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/optparse.rb:1582:in `block in parse_in_order'
 4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/lib/jazzy/config.rb:54:in `block in attach_to_option_parser'
 3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/lib/jazzy/config.rb:35:in `set'
 2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/lib/jazzy/config.rb:35:in `instance_exec'
 1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/lib/jazzy/config.rb:342:in `block in <class:Config>'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jazzy-0.13.2/lib/jazzy/source_declaration/access_control_level.rb:64:in `from_human_string': cannot initialize AccessControlLevel with '' (RuntimeError)
```

Comment: try specifying more details to jazzy, for example:
jazzy --clean --module <module_name> -x -workspace <name>.xcworkspace -scheme <scheme_name> --min-acl private

Comment: This doesn't work for me i just have a project file. What are the module_name and scheme_name? I'm very new to swift. how can i create a workspace if i need to use that? @kerim.ba

Comment: You got the solution ?

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it @Amit

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Jazzy ?

Comment: yeah, it didn't help. I'm working on a new project and I'm going to try it on there when i finish that one. just to see if it has to be done on .xcworkspace. i have no idea how to fix the issue.

Comment: Reinstalling the Jazzy worked for me that's why I am asking. Are you getting any error while doing `sudo gem install jazzy` ?

Comment: tried to do it now but still didn't work. @Amit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211656/discussion-between-amit-and-petter-braka).

Comment: okay thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of people searching on google, when jazzy reports skipped items and generates 0% of documentation, invoke jazzy in the following way:

```
jazzy --min-acl <internal|fileprivate|private>
```

Swift is internal unless you specify the access otherwise.

Here is a link to the github readme discussing this topic: https://github.com/realm/jazzy#controlling-what-is-documented